# SimpleITK python programming

Tags: python, image-processing, itk

I'm fairly new to python programming and definitely new to simpleITK. I'm trying to put together a segmentation filter that can segment out the liver from 3D images. Because i'm so new to programming in general, i'm not sure where to start. I've looked at the simpleITK notebooks which go over some filters for segmentation but overall i'm pretty confused, mainly, if i want to use multiple filters does everything go in one .py file ... ? I was hoping someone could guide me towards a starting point or tell me about a tutorial i could read through to figure out what to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This PyScience post](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/image-segmentation-with-python-and-simpleitk/) has a very nice tutorial on image segmentation using SimpleITK in python.

With a bit more information on the your problem, I might be able to provide some more specific help (i.e. what type of images are you using, do you know how to read an image into SimpleITK, are you looking for a completely automatic solution or is manual intervention allowed, etc.)